# MySQL keeps running out of memory with Wordpress, how much memory do I need?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have been experiencing MySQL crashing recently and really need to figure out what I need to do to get this to stop.

I have a 2GB Digital Ocean server running the following:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP v5.5.9
- Apache v20120211
- MySQL v5.5.43
- Wordpress v4.2

I also have 2GB of swap.

The last time MySQL crashed this was in my error log

http://laravel.io/bin/E304E

The important part seems (to me) to be this

```
InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

I am getting about 2000 page views per day. I thought this should be easily enough memory to run the site.

Can anyone give me some ideas what I can do or what I definitely need to do to stop this happening?

Thanks

Comment: What about using some cache plugin on wordpress, like WP Super Cache or W3 Total Cache?

Comment: What is the memory usage on the machine?

Comment: In all likelihood your server has crashed and this error message is at reboot. Please see this question for some good dialog about the problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/intermittent-mysql-crashes-with-error-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-t#25171

Answer (score 0):

2000 page views per day is well within the range of what your server can handle. It's possible you're getting hit by bots and/or Apache isn't configured well for your server size.

Apache2Buddy is a quick diagnostic tool to help with your Apache configurations. `$ curl -L http://apache2buddy.pl/ | perl`. It'll print out a report with suggested configuration adjustments given your RAM available and application size. My guess is that you'll need to update MaxRequestWorkers (located at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf`) to something smaller.

I'm also guessing that you have bots hitting your site, which is causing the huge volume of traffic that is crashing Apache. Check your access logs `$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log`.

I wrote an article on this situation if you want a deeper explanation, a method to stress test, or ideas on how to block some of the bot traffic: http://brunzino.github.io/blog/2016/05/21/solution-how-to-debug-intermittent-error-establishing-database-connection/

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll certainly give it a go